# Google Play purchases are not supported in your country

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

This was reported to us by one of our client at Myanmar, the app is totally free and has no Admob dependencies but there is this two dependency we added:

```
//Required: Google Play Services Ads Identifier (If publishing to Google Play)
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier:17.0.1'

    //Required: Install Referrer (If publishing to Google Play)
    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.2'
```

Not familiar with this two dependency very much and how they work so my question is, is it possible that this two is causing the issue despite the app is free thus does not need any Google Play purchases support.

[image]

Comment: One of my app users has reported this same error today. He lives in Portugal, and should be able to buy without problems because my app subscriptions are setup to be available in all countries.